# Firestore data modeling and angularFire

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have data model like this

```
Players-->root collection

Sports--->root collection

Players_Sports---root collection
```

[image: Player Collection]

[image: Sports collection]

[image]

I want get all the sports(Multiple sport) details or document player belongs. 
For this I am using angularFireStore5

**First**, I am getting 
Player details like this

```
this.db.collection('players').doc(id).get().toPromise()
```

**Second**, I am getting Player(user) linked PlayerSport

```
db.collection<any>('PlayerSports',ref => ref.where('playerId', '==', id) ).get().toPromise()
```

**Third**,  I am trying to get Sports details based on ID'S,

```
db.collection<any>('sportsType', ref => ref.where('sportsType' 'in' [sportsIDs])).get().toPromise()
```

where SportIDs is arrary of ID that are linked in player_sports

First and Second steps works fine, but third steps is not giving any data or response

Could you please let me know where is the problem,
is it in Data model or code? my guess is that data model is not correct. Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `sportsType` field in the `sportsType` document as far as I can see.

If you're trying to find documents based on their `SportsId` field, you'll want `ref.where('SportsId'...`.

---

**Update**

It seems that you're trying to find a document by its ID, which you can do with:

```
ref.doc(sportsIDs)
```

If you want to get multiple documents, or get a single document as a collection, you can use:

```
ref.where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() 'in' [sportsIDs])
```

Comment: But sportsId is not there in SportyType collection, how it will fetch data?

Comment: Ah wait... is that value used as the document name then? I added an update on how to do that.

Comment: I am trying to run your code but getting this error
'firebase' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
Do I need to import?

Comment: Yes, you will need to `import` the Firebase SDK to be able to use `firebase.firestore` I highly recommend searching for the error message btw, as this error message has come up a few times in the past weeks.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting the data from firebase and storing it inside a list so the app can access it later.

```
void getDataF(){
databaseReference
.collection("TableName")
.getDocuments()
.then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
snapshot.documents.forEach((f) { 
iDFacList.add(f.documentID);
dbFacList.add(f.data["FieldName"]);
});
});
}
```